# python - auto reply email

Tags: python, html, email, reply

I want to create a python script to auto reply html mail from postfix pipe:
Example in aliases file:

```
testmail: "| python /opt/script/autoreply.py /opt/script/autoreply.html"
```

The autoreply.html will contain the html email.
There is an example from python:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id5

to send an alternative MIMEMultipart

I want to use that example to my script. The idea is load the autoreply.html file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#autoreply.py
import smtplib
import sys
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "you@email.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
html = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text.read(), 'plain')
text.close()
part2 = MIMEText(html.read(), 'html')
html.close()

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtprelay.gameloft.org')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

how can I edit that script to let the pipe send an html (autoreply.html) email? Change the from address, to address, from the original message, load the autoreply.html.
If there is no autoreply.txt file, load the autoreply.html by default. (the example from python need the text/plain)

Can someone help me? It is quite complex to me.
Thanks!

Comment: Look into this, This will be helpful in this regard. [See the code](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2008-May/msg00165.html)